# Identity - One to one relationship with RegisterViewModel

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm new to MVC and have been pulling my hair out with this one. I'm already going bold so need someone to rescue what's left!

I'm using `asp.net Identity` and trying to create a **one-to-one relationship** between `RegisterViewModel` and StoreDetails and really hope someone can help me out!

Here is my `RegisterViewModel`:

```
   public class RegisterViewModel
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public virtual StoreDetails StoreDetails { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my StoreDetails model:

```
public class StoreDetails
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("RegisterViewModel")]
    public string StoreName { get; set; }

    public virtual RegisterViewModel RegisterViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser {

                // PERSONAL DETAILS
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName
            };

            var storeDetails = new StoreDetails {
                // STORE DETAILS
                StoreName = model.StoreDetails.StoreName
            };


            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");


                // UPDATE DB WITH STORE DETAILS DATA
                var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
                db.StoreDetails.Add(new StoreDetails
                {
                    StoreName = model.StoreDetails.StoreName
                });
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

What i'm looking to achieve is on registration the StoreDetails table is generated with the following input:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StoreDetails.StoreName)
```

If you need any further details please ask.

Thanks

Comment: is `RegisterViewModel` and `StoreDetails` in your DataBase? and please describe your problem mode detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegisterViewModel is not a real entity i.e person that gets saved into the database by EF. All it is is a carrier object that passes the values of email and password into the real User/person object called `ApplicationUser`. This is a view-model and not a real model.

in your example you added StoreDetails in the RegisterViewModel which is correct. But you also need to add this in your ApplicationUser class as a property.

```
public class ApplicationUser {

public virtual StoreDetails StoreDetails { get; set; }
```

Then run your migrations.

Adding anything to the RegisterViewModel is made to pass data from the view layer in a way to safe guard the object thats going into your db.

i.e 
doing this doesnt do anything because the viewmodel doesnt live in the db

```
public class StoreDetails
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("RegisterViewModel")] //this will not work remove
    public string StoreName { get; set; }

    public virtual RegisterViewModel RegisterViewModel { get; set; }// remove
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public Ienumerable<StoreDetails> StoreDetails { get; set; }

public int StoreDetailsId { get; set; }
```

In controller:

```
using (var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
{
    model.StoreDetails = db.StoreDetails.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you gave an explanation of why this solves the original question. Also, try to keep non-code text out of the code block format or use the appropriate comment syntax so other understand these additions in context.